# Window 7 won't load

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have a PC with a Windows 7 OS, the problem is that it won't load. All I can see is a black screen and a mouse cursor. I tried to enter in a safe mode, but still the problem exist. I also tried to use hirens boot and run its Mini Windows XP, but sad to say Mini Windows XP crashed! What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure. First of all make sure all external drives and usb devices are physically removed from all ports. This has happened to me before and the reason was boot was trying to read operating system on attached storage but failed. Maybe check your BIOS settings as well. Good luck.

Comment: Also, if you can run in Safe Mode backup recovery from a previous point in time when all was fine.

Comment: That is one of my problem, I cant run it in Safe Mode.

Comment: Have you tried Recovery repair only?

Comment: Maybe your MBR is damaged. You can possibly use Knoppix to repair it. You would have to have access to another computer to create a Live disk or put it on usb flash drive. http://www.knoppix.org/   You can change language from German to English in the top right corner of page.

Comment: Has anyone opened up the PC lately and possibly gotten cables lose? Any unusual beeps upon POST? Has the PC had dust evacuated from the sensitive guts, especially power supply and cpu heat sink and fan?

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model number, PC or laptop? Or is this a byo box?

Comment: At this point, when I boot the pc, it says No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key.

Comment: I check the hard disk with HDD Tools, sad to say no more Hard Disk in the PC

Comment: My Hard Disk is already dead!

Comment: That isn't necessarily true. I've gotten the same warning before but disk wasn't dead. Try reinstalling OS.

Comment: I would bet you can use that hard drive as a backup. I think the MBR is corrupted. It takes a lot for me to give up on a drive. You shouldn't give up so easily. Make that Knoppix disk. If it can see the files on that drive then you'll see it still has life left. Knoppix needs no hard disk to run on.

Comment: I checked it using HDD SMART Viewer 2.00, but no HDD was found in the system.